# Recursivly read a directory in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to server side programming and NodeJS

I need to read a directory recursively to get the file name of each file in this directory ( an array of file names ( relative paths) should be returned)

I think it is some thing very common so I am hoping if someone can share the code. Or just tell me the right methods to call.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting all filenames in a directory with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my first shot at it.

```
fs = require('fs');

function getDirectoryFiles(directory, callback) {
  fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file){
      fs.stat(directory + '/' + file, function(err, stats) {
        if(stats.isFile()) {
          callback(directory + '/' + file);
        }
        if(stats.isDirectory()) {
          getDirectoryFiles(directory + '/' + file, callback);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

getDirectoryFiles('.', function(file_with_path) {
  console.log(file_with_path);
});
```

Of course instead of the `console.log` in the callback handling function you could push the values in a global array.

Comment: This was the most valuable answer for me! Thanks you, sir!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with the files method of the [node-dir module](https://github.com/fshost/node-dir):

Install the module

```
npm install node-dir
```

Then the code is as simple as

```
var dir = require('node-dir');

dir.files(__dirname, function(err, files) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(files);
});
```

This will recurse through all subdirectories and result will be an array of file paths.

Answer (score 1):

Also this may help: [do async task on each file recursively and execute callback when done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951350/synchronize-asynchronous-calls-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

check out loaddir
https://npmjs.org/package/loaddir

`npm install loaddir`

```
  loaddir = require('loaddir')

  allJavascripts = []
  loaddir({
    path: __dirname + '/public/javascripts',
    callback: function(){  allJavascripts.push(this.relativePath + this.baseName); }
  })
```

You can use `fileName` instead of `baseName` if you need the extension as well.