# Why do JavaScript functions need to have the keyword "async"? Isn't the "await" keyword enough?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

For instance, why does the function below need to have "async"? Isn't using *await* specific enough for the compiler to parse the code without ambiguity?

```
// Why do we need async here?
async function foo() {
  var user = await getUser(user_id);
  console.log(user);
}
```

Is it for backward compatibility reasons? (I can't think of any code that uses the *await* keyboard in standard JavaScript...)?

Is it mainly for clarity to make it clear that this function uses the new *async* keyword?

Comment: I can only imagine that it makes parsing easier....

Comment: In this example, it wouldn't make much sense.  You're running something asynchronously and then telling it to wait for results from getUser.  It might make more sense in the context of a larger function.

Comment: You might find this blog useful: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html I agree it's probably a parsing issue. From the blog: "When a function is declared as async it is then able to yield execution to the calling code while it awaits for a promise to be resolved. "

Comment: I guess the why boils down to *"because the spec says so"*, or at least probably will when there is a spec, and that's the pattern commonly used in other languages implenting async/await.

Comment: Much like function generators, why do they need a *?

Comment: Fact is, in order to know for sure, you have to talk to the person you proposed this feature. This isn't really a good fit for Stack Overflow, even if it is an interesting question in itself.

Comment: Why someone stupid always close others' questions even if they are good questions?

Comment: See also [Why is it necessary to have the async keyword before the function keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31483342/1048572)

Answer (score 8):

From a language perspective, the `async`/`await` keywords in JavaScript are designed *very* closely to the way they work in C#.

I have an old blog post that describes some discussions around why `async` was explicitly added in C#: [see `Inferring "async"` here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html). In short, adding keywords is a potentially breaking change to a language; imagine an existing app that uses a `var await = false;` or something of that nature.

Or, for an example of how this could be more ambiguous, `var await = function() {};`, which would be used as `await (x);`. Looking at the usage `await (x);`, the compiler would have a hard time deciding what kind of expression that is. You could argue that `await` is a keyword *unless* there's a variable in scope with that name, but that gets really hairy.

A much cleaner solution is to introduce a *pair* of keywords, so `async` (which is used only for functions and lambdas, and is not ambiguous) enables the `await` keyword, but only within that scope. There are similar benefits to having `function*` denote generators, rather than just the presence of `yield`.

It's not only less ambiguous (maintaining backwards compatibility with code that uses `await` for other things), but it is also easier for both software *and* humans to parse.