# Difference between async/await and ES6 yield with generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, ecmascript-next

I was just reading this fantastic article «[Generators](https://www.promisejs.org/generators)» and it clearly highlights this function, which is a helper function for handling generator functions:

```js
function async(makeGenerator){
  return function () {
    var generator = makeGenerator.apply(this, arguments);

    function handle(result){
      // result => { done: [Boolean], value: [Object] }
      if (result.done) return Promise.resolve(result.value);

      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(function (res){
        return handle(generator.next(res));
      }, function (err){
        return handle(generator.throw(err));
      });
    }

    try {
      return handle(generator.next());
    } catch (ex) {
      return Promise.reject(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

*which I hypothesize is more or less the way the `async` keyword is implemented with `async`/`await`.* So the question is, if that is the case, then what the heck is the difference between the `await` keyword and the `yield` keyword? Does `await` always turn something into a promise, whereas `yield` makes no such guarantee? That is my best guess!

You can also see how `async`/`await` is similar to `yield` with generators in this article where he describes the 'spawn' function [ES7 async functions](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions).

Comment: async function -> a  coroutine. generator -> iterator which uses a coroutine to manage its inner iterations mechanism. await suspends a coroutine, while yield return a result from a coroutine which some generator uses

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7. Please read tag description.

Comment: @david haim, yeah but async await is built on top of generators so they are not distinct

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well, it turns out that there is a very close relationship between `async`/`await` and generators. And I believe `async`/`await` will always be built on generators. If you look at the way Babel transpiles `async`/`await`:

Babel takes this:

```js
this.it('is a test', async function () {

    const foo = await 3;
    const bar = await new Promise(resolve => resolve('7'));
    const baz = bar * foo;
    console.log(baz);

});
```

and turns it into this

```js
function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
    return function () {
        var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            function step(key, arg) {
                try {
                    var info = gen[key](arg);
                    var value = info.value;
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }
                if (info.done) {
                    resolve(value);
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) {
                        return step("next", value);
                    }, function (err) {
                        return step("throw", err);
                    });
                }
            }

            return step("next");
        });
    };
}


this.it('is a test', _asyncToGenerator(function* () {   // << now it's a generator

    const foo = yield 3;    //  <<< now it's yield, not await
    const bar = yield new Promise(resolve => resolve(7));
    const baz = bar * foo;
    console.log(baz);

}));
```

you do the math.

This makes it look like the `async` keyword is just that wrapper function, but if that's the case then `await` just gets turned into `yield`, there will probably be a bit more to the picture later on when they become native.

You can see more of an explanation for this here:
https://www.promisejs.org/generators/

Comment: NodeJS has native async/await for a while now, without generators: https://codeforgeek.com/2017/02/asyncawait-function-officially-shipped-nodejs-7-6-0/

Comment: @Bram native implementation absolutely uses generators under the hood, same thing, just abstracted away.

Comment: I don't think so. Async/await is natively implemented in the V8 engine. Generators where a ES6 feature, async/await is ES7. It was part of the 5.5 release of the V8 engine (which is used in Node): https://v8project.blogspot.nl/2016/10/v8-release-55.html. It is possible to transpile ES7 async/await into ES6 generators, but with new versions of NodeJS this is no longer needed, and the performance of async/await even seems to be better then generators: https://medium.com/@markherhold/generators-vs-async-await-performance-806d8375a01a

Comment: async/await uses generators to do its thing

Comment: @AlexanderMills can you please share some legit resources which says async/await uses generators internally? check this ans stackoverflow.com/a/39384160/3933557 which contradicts this argument. I think , just because Babel uses generators, it does not mean it is implemented similarly under the hood. Any thoughts on this

Comment: The short version in V8, from what I can tell, is *sort of*. Yes, async is written using generator machinery: see [this comment](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/17a99fec258bcc07ea9fc5e4fabcce259751db03/src/builtins/builtins-async-function-gen.cc#L247-L254), but from what I can tell they are using internal APIs and specializing the bulitin impls to skip unnecessary checks - presumably because you don't have a handle on the generator object to do evil things on.

Answer (score 52):

`yield` can be considered to be the building block of `await`. `yield` takes the value it's given and passes it to the caller. The caller can then do whatever it wishes with that value (1). Later the caller may give a value back to the generator (via `generator.next()`) which becomes the result of the `yield` expression (2), or an error that will appear to be thrown by the `yield` expression (3).

`async`-`await` can be considered to use `yield`. At (1) the caller (i.e. the `async`-`await` driver - similar to the function you posted) will wrap the value in a promise using a similar algorithm to `new Promise(r => r(value)` (note, *not* `Promise.resolve`, but that's not a big deal). It then waits for the promise to resolve. If it fulfills, it passes the fulfilled value back at (2). If it rejects, it throws the rejection reason as an error at (3).

So the utility of `async`-`await` is this machinery that uses `yield` to unwrap the yielded value as a promise and pass its resolved value back, repeating until the function returns its final value.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384160/3933557 which contradicts this argument. async-await looks similar to yield but it uses promises chain under the hood. Please share if you have any good resource says "async-await can be considered to use yield".

Comment: I'm not sure how you're taking that answer to be "contradicting this argument", because it's saying the same thing as this answer. >In the meantime, transpilers like Babel allow you to write async/await and convert the code to generators.

Comment: its says babel convert to generators but what you are saying is 
"yield can be considered to be the building block of await" and "async-await can be considered to use yield.". which is not correct to my understanding (subject to correction). async-await internally uses promise chains as mentioned in that answer. i want to understand if there is something i am missing, can you please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: This answer does not make the claim that all ES engines in the whole world internally implement promises using generators. Some may; some may not; it is irrelevant to the question that this is an answer to. Nevertheless, the way promises work can be understood using generators with a particular way to drive the generator, and that is what this answer explains.

Answer (score 32):

> what the heck is the difference between the `await` keyword and the `yield` keyword?

The `await` keyword is only to be used in `async function`s, while the `yield` keyword is only to be used in generator `function*`s. And those are obviously different as well - the one returns promises, the other returns generators.

> Does `await` always turn something into a promise, whereas `yield` makes no such guarantee?

Yes, `await` will call `Promise.resolve` on the awaited value.

`yield` just yields the value outside of the generator.

Comment: A minor nit, but as I mentioned in my answer the spec doesn't use Promise.resolve (it used to earlier), it uses PromiseCapability::resolve which is more accurately represented by the Promise constructor.

Comment: @Arnavion: [`Promise.resolve`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve) uses exactly the same `new PromiseCapability(%Promise%)` that the async/await spec uses directly, I just thought `Promise.resolve` is better to understand.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` has an extra "IsPromise == true? then return same value" short-circuit that async does not have. That is, `await p` where `p` is a promise will return a new promise that resolves to `p`, whereas `Promise.resolve(p)` would return `p`.

Comment: Oh I missed that - I thought this was only in `Promise.cast` and was deprecated for consistency reasons. But it doesn't matter, we don't really see that promise anyway.

Comment: `var r = await p; console.log(r);` should be transformed to something like: `p.then(console.log);`, while `p` might be created as: `var p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 42));`, so it is wrong to say "await _calls_ Promise.resolve", it is some other code totally far away from the 'await' expression that invokes `Promise.resolve`, so the transformed `await` expression, i.e. `Promise.then(console.log)` would be invoked and print out `42`.

Answer (score 23):

## tl;dr

**Use `async`/`await` 99% of the time over generators.** Why?

1. `async`/`await` directly replaces the most common workflow of promise chains allowing code to be declared as if it was synchronous, dramatically simplifying it.
2. Generators abstract the use case where you would call a series of async-operations that depend on each other and eventually will be in a "done" state. The most simple example would be paging through results that eventually return the last set but you would only call a page as needed, not immediately in succession.
3. `async`/`await` is actually an abstraction built on top of generators to make working with promises easier.

[See very in-depth Explanation of Async/Await vs. Generators](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/modern-javascript-and-asynchronous-programming-generators-yield-vs-async-await-550275cbe433)

Answer (score 6):

Try this test programs which I used to understand `await`/`async` with promises.

**Program #1: without promises it doesn't run in sequence**

```js
function functionA() {
  console.log('functionA called');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('functionA timeout called');
    return 10;
  }, 15000);

}

function functionB(valueA) {
  console.log('functionB called');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('functionB timeout called = ' + valueA);
    return 20 + valueA;
  }, 10000);
}

function functionC(valueA, valueB) {

  console.log('functionC called');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('functionC timeout called = ' + valueA);
    return valueA + valueB;
  }, 10000);

}

async function executeAsyncTask() {
  const valueA = await functionA();
  const valueB = await functionB(valueA);
  return functionC(valueA, valueB);
}
console.log('program started');
executeAsyncTask().then(function(response) {
  console.log('response called = ' + response);
});
console.log('program ended');
```

**Program #2: with promises**

```js
function functionA() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('functionA called');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('functionA timeout called');
      // return 10;
      return resolve(10);
    }, 15000);
  });
}

function functionB(valueA) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('functionB called');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('functionB timeout called = ' + valueA);
      return resolve(20 + valueA);
    }, 10000);

  });
}

function functionC(valueA, valueB) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('functionC called');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('functionC timeout called = ' + valueA);
      return resolve(valueA + valueB);
    }, 10000);

  });
}

async function executeAsyncTask() {
  const valueA = await functionA();
  const valueB = await functionB(valueA);
  return functionC(valueA, valueB);
}
console.log('program started');
executeAsyncTask().then(function(response) {
  console.log('response called = ' + response);
});
console.log('program ended');
```

Answer (score 0):

In many ways, generators are a superset of async/await. Right now async/await has cleaner stack traces than [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co), the most popular async/await-like generator based lib. You can implement your own flavor of async/await using generators and add new features, like built-in support for `yield` on non-promises or building it on RxJS observables.

So, in short, generators give you more flexibility and generator-based libs generally have more features. But async/await is a core part of the language, it's standardized and won't change under you, and you don't need a library to use it. I have a [blog post](http://thecodebarbarian.com/the-difference-between-async-await-and-generators.html) with more details on the difference between async/await and generators.

Answer (score 0):

**The `yield`+`gen.next()`-as-a-language-feature can be used to describe (or implement) the underlying control-flow that `await-async` has abstracted away.**

---

As other answers suggest, `await`-as-a-language-feature is (or can be thought of) an implementation on top of `yield`.

Here is a more intutive understanding for that:

Say we have 42 `awaits` in an async function,  `await A -> await B -> ...`

Deep down it is equivalent to having `yield A -> tries resolve this as a Promise` [1]

`-> if resolvable, we yield B, and repeat [1] for B`

`-> if not resolveable, we throw`

And so we end up with 42 `yields` in a generator. And in our controller we simply keep doing `gen.next()` until it is completed or gets rejected. (ie this is the same as using `await` on an async function that contains 42 `await`.)

This is why lib like redux-saga utilizes generator to then pipe the promises to the saga middleware to be resolved all at one place; thus decoupling the Promises constructions from their evaluations, thus sharing close resemblance to the [Free Monad](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to recursively chain `then()` calls to replicate the behavior of `await` which allows one to invoke `async` routines in a synchronous fashion. A generator function is used to yield back control (and each value) from the callee to the caller, which happens to be the `_asyncToGenerator()` wrapper function.

As mentioned above, this is the trick that Babel uses to create polyfills. I slightly edited the code to make it more readable and added comments.

```js
(async function () {
  const foo = await 3;
  const bar = await new Promise((resolve) => resolve(7));
  const baz = bar * foo;
  console.log(baz);
})();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
  return function () {
    let gen = fn(); // Start the execution of the generator function and store the generator object.
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      function step(func, arg) {
        try {
          let item = gen[func](arg); // Retrieve the function object from the property name and invoke it. Similar to eval(`gen.${func}(arg)`) but safer. If the next() method is called on the generator object, the item value by the generator function is saved and the generator resumes execution. The value passed as an argument is assigned as a result of a yield expression.
          if (item.done) {
            resolve(item.value);
            return; // The executor return value is ignored, but we need to stop the recursion here.
          }
          // The trick is that Promise.resolve() returns a promise object that is resolved with the value given as an argument. If that value is a promise object itself, then it's simply returned as is.
          return Promise.resolve(item.value).then(
            (v) => step("next", v),
            (e) => step("throw", e)
          );
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
          return;
        }
      }
      return step("next");
    });
  };
}

_asyncToGenerator(function* () { // <<< Now it's a generator function.
  const foo = yield 3; // <<< Now it's yield, not await.
  const bar = yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(7)); // <<< Each item is converted to a thenable object and recursively enclosed into chained then() calls.
  const baz = bar * foo;
  console.log(baz);
})();
```