# What is different between asyncData and methods in nuxt js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I currently used

- `asyncData` for getting api data , but it can only used in pages ( not in components) .
- But method can used in **page and component** .

These two method work the same ways and , so I am thinking to use methods for getting api data . 
So I wonder is there any significant between ***asyncData and method*** ?

```
export default {
  async asyncData ({ req }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get(process.env.API_SERVER + `/v1/projects`)
    return { items: data }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      items: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getItems () {
       let { data } = await axios.get(process.env.API_SERVER + `/v1/projects`)
       this.items = data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very big difference:

`asyncData` is a method which gets automatically called before the component gets initialized and therefore before the component data gets set.

Therefore you won't have access to `this` like in your methods.

`asyncData` is important for server side rendering where you want to fetch first your data before your component gets rendered with the fetched data. Nuxt will wait until the data got fetched before initializing and then rendering the component. Otherwise it would be rendered empty.

Methods are first available when the component is initialized.

You'll find more about asyncData [here in the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) and there it's good described.

Answer (score 1):

its like `automatic promise`

once you (ajax) request something then you get `promise` so you add `then` handler so when you get data your `then` code will be executed.

so `ajax` request will take some time so we are making that flow as `async` means continue the flow `but when data received i need to execute some code which i have provided in then function`

same goes with `asyncData`(its just wrapper for data with async capabilities) and `async` method what ever code you write inside will `await` for the `given operation` then when that `operation` is finished method will be executed.

its just like `alert('hello')` which `await` user for to click `ok` then continue the flow.

as well in server-side rendering it work same it will stop execution flow for a while for `incoming data` then again resumes it.

it more on depth with this `js generators` answer (if you are more interested): [Difference between async/await and ES6 yield with generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196608/difference-between-async-await-and-es6-yield-with-generators)