# What is the overhead of Javascript async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

**The question**: Is there, (and if yes, to what extent) a computational overhead in the engine runtime to declare a function as `async` and to eventually `await` as compared to a regular function's return statement ?

```
async function foo() {
    var x = await bar(); // <--- bar() is non-blocking so await to get the return value
    return x; // the return value is wrapped in a Promise because of async
}
```

Versus

```
function foo() {
    var x = bar(); // <--- bar() is blocking inside its body so we get the return value
    return new Promise(resolve => { resolve(x); }); // return a Promise manually
}
```

**Context**:

Due to the asynchronous direction taken by Javascript (and i.e. Nodejs), why did they not consider every function to be asynchronous (as per `async` keyword) by default ?

This way, people could just decide to treat any function call as a `Promise` and play the asynchronous game, or just `await` what is necessary.

I suppose that `await`-ing within a function body creates the overhead of stacking the local function's scope whereas the normal event loop proceeds when the function returns and does not have to push the inner function scope to the stack ?

This comes down to a bonus question : in a complex hyerarchy of classes that (somewhere deep) requires one synchronous IO operation (see note) that would ideally be `await`'ed. It is only possible if that method is marked as `async`. Which in turn required the calling function to be `async` to be able to `await` it again and so forth. Thus, everything marked `async` and `await` when needed... How to deal with such a scenario ?

**Note**: Please do not argue about the necessity of not-doing any sync operations as this is not the point.

**Note 2**: This question is not about what is `await` or `async` nor when it executes. This question is about performance and the internals of the language (even though multiple implementations exist, there may be a inherent semantic overhead to the concept).

Comment: async functions will execute at the earliest one event loop tick later. this question is not a good format for stackoverflow

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong in my question. Can you elaborate @AndyRay

Comment: You can treat every function async if you want to. `await` will also work for non-promise values. *"How to deal with such a scenario ?"* There is not a new way to handle this situation. `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for promises. You do exactly the same thing you do when dealing with promises.

Comment: "*bar() is blocking inside its body*" - that doesn't work. Even `async function`s are still asynchronous - non-blocking, that's the whole point of concurrency in node.js.

Comment: "*why did they not consider every function to be asynchronous by default?*" - because not every function should return a promise. If you meant that it should just "block" under the hood like there's an `await` placed everywhere: [that would be an absolutely horrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447289/1048572).

Comment: Do you understand how async functions work, and how they desugar to promise `then` calls?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An async function has inherent overhead compared to a synchronous function.
It's certainly possible to make everything async but you would likely run into performance issues pretty quickly.

#### Sync vs Async

A function returns a value.

An `async` function creates a Promise object to return from the function. The Promise object is set up to maintain the state of the asynchronous task and handle errors or subsequent chained calls. The promise will be resolved or rejected after the next tick of the event loop. (That's a bit brief, [read the the spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) if you want detail) This has both a memory and processing overhead compared to a simple function call and return value.

Quantifying the overhead is a bit useless though, as most async functions are async due to them having to wait for an external Node.js thread to complete some work, normally doing slow IO.  The overhead in setting up the Promise is pretty minimal compared to the overall time of the operation, especially if the alternative is to block the main JS thread.

Synchronous code on the other hand, runs immediately in the main JS thread. The crossover area is scheduling synchronous code, either for timing or for "throttling" the use of the main JS thread onto the next tick so GC and other async tasks get a chance to run.

If you're in a tight loop parsing a string char by char, you probably don't want to be creating a promise and waiting for it to resolve on each iteration as the memory and time requirements to complete the process will explode quickly.

On the other hand, if all your app does is [query a database](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and dump the results to a [koa](http://koajs.com/) http response then your likely doing most things in an async promise (although underneath there will still be a lot of synchronous functions making that happen).

#### Silly Example

A benchmark of a contrived example, the difference between a sync return and various async methods of resolving the same synchronous operation.

```
const Benchmark = require('benchmark')
const Bluebird = require('bluebird')

let a = 3
 
const asyncFn = async function asyncFn(){
  a = 3
  return a+2
}

const cb = function(cb){
  cb(null, true)
}
let suite = new Benchmark.Suite()
suite
  .add('fn', function() {
    a = 3
    return a+2
  })
  .add('cb', {
    defer: true,
    fn: function(deferred) {
      process.nextTick(()=> deferred.resolve(a+2))
    }
  })
  .add('async', {
    defer: true,
    fn: async function(deferred) {
      let res = await asyncFn()
      deferred.resolve(res)
    }
  }) 
  .add('promise', {
    defer: true,
    fn: function(deferred) {
      a = 3
      return Promise.resolve(a+2).then(res => deferred.resolve(res))
    }
  })
  .add('bluebird', {
    defer: true,
    fn: function(deferred) {
      a = 3
      return Bluebird.resolve(a+2).then(res => deferred.resolve(res))
    }
  })

  // add listeners
  .on('cycle', event => console.log("%s", event.target))
  .on('complete', function(){
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'))
  })
  .on('error', error => console.error(error))
  .run({ 'async': true })
```

Run

```
→ node promise_resolve.js
fn x 138,794,227 ops/sec ±1.10% (82 runs sampled)
cb x 3,973,527 ops/sec ±0.82% (79 runs sampled)
async x 2,263,856 ops/sec ±1.16% (79 runs sampled)
promise x 2,583,417 ops/sec ±1.09% (81 runs sampled)
bluebird x 3,633,338 ops/sec ±1.40% (76 runs sampled)
Fastest is fn
```

Also check [bluebirds benchmarks](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark) if you want a more detailed comparison of the performance/overhead of the various promise and callback implementations.

```
file                                       time(ms)  memory(MB)
callbacks-baseline.js                           154       33.87
callbacks-suguru03-neo-async-waterfall.js       227       46.11
promises-bluebird-generator.js                  282       41.63
promises-bluebird.js                            363       51.83
promises-cujojs-when.js                         497       63.98
promises-then-promise.js                        534       71.50
promises-tildeio-rsvp.js                        546       83.33
promises-lvivski-davy.js                        556       92.21
promises-ecmascript6-native.js                  632       98.77
generators-tj-co.js                             648       82.54
promises-ecmascript6-asyncawait.js              725      123.58
callbacks-caolan-async-waterfall.js             749      109.32
```

Comment: Answer to the point, this is rare on this very matter ! BTW, I am spawning Nodejs processes (yes a new process) as a command-line utility so the blocking fact is an intended behavior. It is not used as a server to process multiple requests nor treat anything else in parallel. This is why the overhead (although minimal if used only once as you showed) may have a deeper impact if used all over.

Comment: It is worth adding direct async function call to benchmark `let res = asyncFn(); deferred.resolve(res);`

Answer (score -1):

There are some actions that you don't want to await for. For example, if you want to do several XHRs, to load several files at the same time, automatically awaiting would make the loading lineal, and that is not good

Answer (score -1):

The beauty of async/await and Promises is that you can mix them. For multiple XHR requests, you can simply return Promise.all():

```
async function fetchPages() {
    return Promise.all([
        fetch("this.html"),
        fetch("that.html")
    ]);
}

for (var page of fetchPages() { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't have to do with `async`, you can run this same code without `async` in the function signature. It would be different if you had `await Promise.all(...)`.