# Is the eslint rule `require-await` important?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Suppose I have a bunch of similar looking method calls:

```
const a = await getA();
const b = await getB();
const c = await getC();
```

But `getB` looks like this:

```
async function getB() {
  return "B";
}
```

Note that `getB` is marked as `async` though it does not contain an `await`. Suppose that `getA` and `getC` both use `await` in their bodies.

This will cause eslint to indicate that the `require-await` rule has been broken. The question is: is this rule actually important? (Note that I'm using TypeScript -- in case the transpilation step affects the answer.)

I prefer the symmetry of `await`ing all of those functions vs. awaiting only some of them -- is there any downside to leaving a function as `async` even if there is no `await` within it?

To expand a bit, suppose my functions needed to match an interface/type:

```
type MyGetter = () => Promise<string>;
```

Then `getB` would have to return a `Promise<string>` (or be marked as `async`), in order to match the type declaration, so is there any harm in this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the overhead of Javascript async functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900782/what-is-the-overhead-of-javascript-async-functions)

Comment: "_I prefer the symmetry of `await`ing all of those functions vs. awaiting only some of them_": It is valid to `await` any expression (e.g. `await null`), so the functions need not be async for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this rule actually important?

Well, it's trying to point out a possible mistake: that the function is returning a promise, but doesn't need to.

As you know, `async` functions return promises. But you typically only make a function `async` because you want to use `await`. If you're not using `await`, then the function probably doesn't need to return a promise at all. The lint rule points this out so you can simplify the function to no longer return a promise, which in turn can simplify code that depends on this function.

But then again, as you mentioned, it might be that you're intentionally trying to return a `Promise<string>` and you find it more convenient to do this with the `async` keyword than with something like this:

```
function getB() {
  return Promise.resolve("B")
}
```

You'll need to make a decision about how useful you find the rule to be. If you find it's rarely/never catching any mistakes, and/or you're frequently using `async` to wrap a value in a promise, then maybe the rule isn't helping much and you could permanently disable it. If it's occasionally useful, you could keep it on and use `//eslint-disable-next-line` to shut it off on a case by case basis.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite follow how this rule would illuminate any _actual_ issues, it seems like it's more about style. Am I missing something (perhaps I'm not understanding your first paragraph correctly)?

Comment: It's not going to catch massive bugs, if that's what you mean. It's about drawing your attention to something unnecessary, so you can simplify your code.