# Waiting for a javascript promise to complete (when I have no other options...)

Tags: javascript, promise

Before you all start screaming about refactoring and callbacks, read the question fully, please :)

I have the following situation in javascript (code simplified for convenience):

```
    function myFunc(){
        var myItems = getItemsAsync(); //this returns a promise

        return {
            settings: {
                type: "items",
                component: "accordion",
                items: myItems //WRONG! This is a promise, not the data itself!
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the situation: I have an external framework that calls `myFunc` and expects the returned object `{settings: etc...}` to have all values already filled in, including the `items` sub-object. I have no control over how this framework calls `myFunc`, so I cannot change it to accept a promise or partial result, the returned object must be "ready" when myFunc returns.

Now, as you can see, here's the problem: to obtain the `items` I need to call an API that is asynchronous by design, and returns a promise. Unfortunately, this API is also out of my control, so I cannot modify it to work synchronously.

So basically I am at a stalemate: I have to synchronously return a complete object, but one of the pieces of that object can only be obtained asynchronously!!

Is there a way out of this? All the similar questions I've seen here on SO suggest that waiting for a promise to be complete cannot be done... is it true?

I know what you're all dying to say: "CHANGE EITHER THE CALLER OR THE API", but unfortunately they are both components that are totally out of my control, as they're part of existing systems that i CANNOT modify (due to bureaucratic, rather than technical, reasons)

Any ideas to get out of this?

Comment: check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: if myFunc has to return anything that is obtained asynchronously then it can not return a value synchronously - you will have to change how myFunc is called. There is no way to make asynchronous result synchronous ... just a moments thought and you'd realise why this is impossible

Comment: @JaromandaX : not even with polling/waiting? Sorry if this sounds silly, but I'm not an expert in javascript... why can't this be done?

Comment: a function can't be "put on hold" while something polls or waits

Comment: @JaromandaX then I'm out of luck :/ thanks anyway

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of when the properties of the returned `settings` object are accessed? So for ex when would `settings.items.` be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, luckily for me I found out that the framework I mentioned in my question (the one that calls `myFunc`) has an initialization phase where I can inject as many promises as I want, and the framework will wait for them to complete before proceeding and calling the other stuff, including `myFunc`, so I was able to build my `items` object during this initialization phase and after that it was ready to be used.

This solves my problem, tho it doesn't answer my original question. I'll still wait a couple of days to see if someone knows of a workaround, but from what I've read in the meantime it appears what I want cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

You know the answer already :-) If you have no other options, you have **no options at all**. It's fundamentally impossible to immediately return a value that will be obtained in the future.

That said, there exist [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21819858/1048572) that can halt the world of your caller, if you are able to wrap the entire framework in a Fiber or something similar. Of course that requires a fundamental change to the entire system, but can be done without changing the framework's code. This might cause some [bugs due to unexpected timing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447289/1048572), though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for bringing Fiber to my attention, will come in handy if I find myself in a similar solution again. Luckily (see my answer) I was able to solve this in a "proper" way, but +1 to you for the info.