# JavaScript native fibers

Tags: javascript, fibers

Do you know if native fiber support is planned in a future version of JavaScript? Indeed, it would be very cool if it was possible to write something like :

```
console.log("sleep 3s...");

const value = wait (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
        () => resolve(5),
        3_000
    );
};

console.log("value =", value);    // value = 5 (after 3s)
```

Of course it is possible to have a similar result with `async/await` but the fibers would allow you to pause anywhere in the code without having to be in a function declared `async`.

Indeed it can become very problematic to convert a synchronous function into an asynchronous one because it is necessary to transform all the dependencies in cascade:

```
const a = () => b() + 1;
const b = () => c() + 2;
const c = () => 5;
const value = a();
```

Ok now c becomes asynchronous...

```
const a = async () => (await b()) + 1;
const b = async () => (await c()) + 2;
const c = async () => new Promise(resolve => { ... resolve(5) });
const value = await a();
```

This is a simple example!
With fiber, it would be much easier:

`const c = () => wait resolve => { ... resolve(5) }`

No need to modify a nor b !

PHP has implemented fibers since version 8 :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.fibers.php

- Do you know if native fiber support is planned in a future version of JavaScript?
- Do you know if there is a place where we can see the future innovations planned in JavaScript?
- Is there a place where we can propose innovations for JavaScript?
- Do you think that native fiber support would be a good idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Besides that I forgot to mention it but the stack trace is emptied after await, I don't know if this problem is solved.

Comment: "*pause anywhere in the code without having to be in a function declared `async`*" - that would be a [very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447289/1048572)

Comment: "*Is there a place where we can propose innovations for JavaScript?*" - https://es.discourse.group

Comment: "*Do you know if there is a place where we can see the future innovations planned in JavaScript?*" - https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I far as I know, fiber is not currently planned for a future version of javascript and probably will never be, as javascript is not multithreaded and does not suffer synchronization issues.

Javascript implementations follow more or less the [ECMAscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) standards. You can follow the past and planned evolution on the [ecma website](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/) and the [draft specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/).

As far as I understand fiber, it looks like a way for controlling concurrency in php and I cannot see any use case in javascript. Asynchronicity should be explicit and stopping an execution flow this way does not seem appropriate in Javascript (considering the browser or a node environment).

That said, as you said it can be explicitly implemented in current js (with promises and/or `async`/`await` function), and ES2022 introduced a module level `await` that will turn `import`ing a module with such a construct into an implicit await before the code can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your answer!

It is true that being able to "pause" at any point in the code can become a source of bugs if not handled properly.
But `await` also introduces this danger because it allows other code portions to be executed in parallel.
In other words, you have to be vigorous with the competition, putting locks where necessary.

I have just created the topic on https://es.discourse.group/t/javascript-native-fibers/1281.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that with `await` it is obvious (being restricted by the syntax) *where* code may be interleaved and it might be necessary to put a lock. Without `await`, it could be anywhere, and you'd have to lock *everything*.

Comment: Remember: javascript is not multitreaded, context is implicitely synchronized. Locks as other multithreaded language imply are not needed. In some edge cases you may need semaphores though.