# TS1163: Typescript wont allow yield within functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

I know it doesn't allow this, but why? Feels like an unnecessary limitation of the language / compiler...

Something as simple as this wont work:

```
*(array:number[]){
    array.forEach(i => yield i+1)
}
```

Of course this could be replaced with a for loop:

```
*(array:number[]){
    for (const i of array)
        yield i + 1
    }
```

But a more practical example might be:

```
async*(){
    await pollX(async () => {
        const x = getX();
        for (const value of x.values)
            yield value
        return x.stop
    })
```

Now it's not a simple - or even possible - refactor (without changing the underlying `pollX` function to be an async-generator itself (which I may not have control over)

---

It seems like the JS engine could obviously restructure the code for me - just like it does with `async-await => promises`

Similarly, before async await, some code became an utter mess of nested promise callbacks; here, you can get into an utter mess of yield hacking (that would be easily solved if the engine just implemented the restructuring).

So far, none of the answers really answer the question - ultimately, it seems possible, but maybe was not a priority for the engine developers? Or is it just not possible (this is my question).

Comment: The other questions about this topic linked also ask "why" question, although the answers focus on how to overcome it.  See https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#sec_generators-are-shallow for "why"; generators are *shallow* so they're easy to implement. If `yield` had to pause nested functions it would make things very very difficult for JS engines. That would require arbitrary coroutines.

Comment: "*Now it's not as simple - or even possible - to refactor*" - so how would you expect the JS engine to do the impossible?

Comment: @jcalz Not just difficult for JS engines, but also for programmers. If any function you're calling could on its own decide to suspend and only resume later asynchronously, [your code would have lots of race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447289/1048572).

Comment: `so how would you expect the JS engine to do the impossible`
@Bergi what you're saying makes no sense... The refactor I was talking about is impossible *due to limitations with the engine*...

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi What I'm saying that this is impossible to implement in the engine for the same reason that you cannot refactor your code without breaking up `pollX`. There is no such restructuring, automatic or not.

Comment: It's not clear why you say "*It seems like the JS engine could obviously restructure the code for me*" - what would the transformed code look like? It's not obvious for me, especially if I have no idea what `pollX` does (and I couldn't give a general algorithm). Notice that for `async`/`await`, it is a **local** transformation of `await` to `.then()`, no magic.