# Is there any C# GetAwaiter equivalent in NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, async-await

I have this code:

```
async function test() {
    var mongo = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    var db = await mongo.db(databaseName);
    var audit = db.collection(collectionName);
    var result = await audit.find({}).toArray();
    return arrayData;
}

var myData = test();
```

But apparently the myData is still the promise object. In C# i know there is function `GetAwaiter` to make it wait for the promise to be finished, is there any equivalent of that in NodeJS? or is there any alternative fort this case? thank you.

Comment: `(async () => {var myData = await test();})();`. That is to say, IIFE. FYI, C# supports `async` `Main`s now :)

Comment: I do not completely understand why do you need GetAwaiter to wait for task to finish - you can do the same thing with Task object (like .Result or await).

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is recommended over `.Result`, if you cannot `await`. IIRC it has to do with exception propagation. But with the ability to write `async Task Main(string[] args)` it isn't needed much these days.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets without using GetAwaiter, you will need to put a more indentation or create a new function which makes the code harder to read and seems messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! All `async` functions return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and you need to either `await` them from inside another `async` function, or `then` them:

So you can either:

```
(async () => {
    var myData = await test();
})();
```

or

```
test().then(data => {
    var myData = data;
});
```

In other words, there's no way in Node to turn an `async` function into a `sync` function. It's **async all the way**, which by the way is also the recommended approach in C#.

---

N.B. When you use `await` on a promise, exceptions are **thrown**, so you need to encompass your `await` statement in a try/catch block. When using `.then()` however, you're expected to also specify a `.catch()` method to handle errors.

Comment: ah man! i know this one and i am hoping that this is not the answer that will come, but i quite expect that this one will come. Ok so far i think this is the only possible way to do

Comment: I hear you! I also come from a C# background, and it was sometimes handy to be able to `wait` synchronously on an async operation. But in Node, there's no way around it (and probably for good reason.) My suggestion is to embrace the async and promises approach. You'll soon get used to it. Good luck :)

Comment: i got what you mean, i was about to do the one that you are describing, but i still looking for a possible approach to be able just like C#

Comment: I sincerely advise against blocking on an async operation, as this can degrade your application performance and definitely breaks the appropriate pattern and usage of async operations. With the `async/await` keywords, you can easily and neatly perform async operations and maintain a linear code. However, if you really are looking for a way to convert an async operation into sync (again, don't, if possible) look here for an approach/hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819858/how-to-wrap-async-function-calls-into-a-sync-function-in-node-js-or-javascript